# Слетают добавленные товары в корзину woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Сталкиваюсь второй раз с проблемой. На сайте wordpress+woocommerce у клиента слетают из корзины добавленные товары. Клиент зол, но Я даже не понимаю в какую сторону копать. Он заходит на сайт, а ему пишет 'Товар удалён из вашей корзины, т.к. больше не доступен для покупки' и т.д. Товары обновляются через All Import csv, могут ли быть у него глюки? Обновляется часто, но слетает корзина редко.

Comment: Если при импорте меняется ID товара то он будет удален из корзины

Comment: Как связаны импорт товаров и корзина? Когда слетают?